# Why do i get undefined index when i have no FORMS in the code

Tags: php, forms, undefined-index

So i want to make a dinamyic menu but i got stuck at undefined index problem can you help me figure out why ?

```
<?php

include_once('includes/connection.php');
include_once('includes/articol.php');

$articol = new articol;
$articole = $articol->fetch_all();
?>
```

And the code from the body

```
<li  id="current"><a class="links" href="index.html">Acasa</a></li>
          <?php foreach ($articole as $articol) { ?>
          <li><a class="links" href="articol.php?id=<?php echo $articol['articol_id']; ?>">

          <?php echo $articol['articol_titlu']; ?>


          </a></li>
          <li><a class="links" href="galben.html">Galben</a></li>
          <li><a class="links" href="albastru.html">Albastru</a></li>
          <li><a class="links" href="drapel.html">Drapel</a></li>
          <li><a class="links" href="despre.html">Despre</a></li>
          <li><a class="links" href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <?php } ?>
```

I got undefined index at

```
<li><a class="links" href="articol.php?id=<?php echo $articol['articol_id']; ?>">

          <?php echo $articol['articol_titlu']; ?>
```

Comment: This isn't a *form* error, it means you are trying to access a key (index) of an array that doesn't exist in the array. Check your code to make sure each array actually has a key called `articol_id` and `articol_titlu`. A simple typo in your field name will generate this. In your query, are you returning the data such as `select articol_id as ID...` for example?

Comment: Well not quite like you said the articol_id and articol_titlu are taken from the database `class articol {
 public function fetch_all() {
  global $db_conx;
  $query = $db_conx->prepare("SELECT * FROM articol");
  $query->execute();
  $resultSet = $query->get_result();
  $result = $resultSet->fetch_all();
  return $result;
  
  
 }
}`